# How to notify Client once on Database update using SignalR?

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, signalr, sqldependency

```
namespace somename
{
    public class ClaimInfoRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<ClaimInfo> GetData()
        {

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT count(1) FROM [dbo].[table] WHERE ClaimStatus=8", connection))
                {
                    // Make sure the command object does not already have
                    // a notification object associated with it.
                    command.Notification = null;

                        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                            .Select(x => new ClaimInfo()
                            {
                                ClaimStatus = x.GetInt32(0)
                            }).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
          void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                //from here we will send notification message to client
                IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ClaimHub>();
                context.Clients.All.notify();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the if condition `if(e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)` It works, But it goes into infinite loop(notifies again and again), I want to notify only once if there is a change..!! any help will be Appreciated..

Comment: I have Followed this link -  http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency

Comment: what is the error that you get? or is it that `if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)` block is false?

Comment: If i add if block it doesn't any error..!!

Comment: If I add If block..! my SignalR also stops Working

Comment: put a breakpoint in the **if block** and check what the status is...

Comment: It is not going Inside In it..!! When i change Values In Database .!!!

Comment: isn't `dependency_OnChange` fired at all?

Comment: dependency_OnChange firing constantly but it doesn't go inside if block

Comment: could you tell me what you get at e.type?